# Powershell regex

Tags: regex, string, powershell, text

Is there a Powershell regex command I could use to replace the last consecutive zero in a text string with a "M". For Example:

```
$Pattern = @("000123456", "012345678", "000000001", "000120000")
```

Final result:

```
00M123456
M12345678
0000000M1
00M120000
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for the following regex:

```
"^(0*)0"
```

The regex searches for a consecutive string of `0` at the beginning `^` of the string. It captures all the `0` except the one for replacement. `"^0(0*)"` also works, since we only need to take note of the number of `0` which we don't touch.

With the replacement string:

```
'$1M'
```

Note that `$1` is denotes the text captured by the first capturing group, which is `(0*)` in the regex.

Example by @SegFault:

```
"000120000" -replace "^(0*)0", '$1M'
```

Comment: Would the line read "$Pattern | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "^(0*)0", "$1M""? Thanks. Sorry, I'm not too familiar with regex, but I thought that would be the way to go.

Comment: @atownson: Sorry, but I am unfamiliar with PowerShell. I know PowerShell uses .NET regex and can write a regex, but I can't write PowerShell command to do it.

Comment: This answer is good, but use single quotes for the replacement string in powershell.  `"000120000" -replace "^(0*)0",'$1M'` for example.